# Como convertir este menu a un menu hamburgesa, bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap

Tengo la siguiente barra de navegación, que me gustaría convertir en un menú de hamburguesas cuando la visualizo en pantallas pequeñas.

```
!-- Navbar-->
        <nav
          id="navHeader"
          class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light fixed-top scrolling-navbar flex-column"
        >
          <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-between scroll">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
              <img src="@/assets/img/elements/mini_logo.png" />
            </a>
            <ul class="navbar-nav pd-right-header">
              <li class="nav-item mr-2">
                <a class="nav-link text-truncate" href="#">
                  <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'phone-alt']" class="icon-blue" />
                  <strong class="pd-icon-header">440-XXX-XXXX</strong>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-truncate" href="#">
                  <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'envelope']" class="icon-blue" />
                  <strong class="pd-icon-header">email@emaileamil.com</strong>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <button
            class="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarNav"
            aria-controls="navbarNav"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation"
          >
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse col-12 scroll" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto w-100">
              <li class="nav-item mg-items-header">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="#about">HOME</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item mg-items-header">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#opportunities">OPPORTUNITIES</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
```

Visually it is like that:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

As you will see, it covers 2 rows, so when it is displayed on a small screen it should only be with the hamburger menu

And it looks like this:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor traduce el resto de tu pregunta. Tip: el menú hamburguesa es más sencillo crearlo en su propia estructura y mostrar uno u otro según el breakpoint. Hay formas para leer tu menú y recrear el HTML para la hamburguesa pero hacen más lenta la página.